# Photoshop: snapchat filter from image

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing, image-editing

Is there a way of taking a snapchat filter off a saved image? Its a leopard nose and ears and would like to know if i can get them off or if any one else could?

Comment: It can be possible but depending on the image it may be very very time consuming to do. Do you have any specific questions on how to do this?

Comment: My kids showed me some snapchat "filters" the other day that were completely unrecognisable as even being a photo... if it's anything like that then the answer is no, not a chance.

Answer (score 1):

**There's no "magic' tool to remove the images Snapchat places over photos.**

I realize adding filters is merely a tap away.. and that's it. Removing the filter are *not* that easy.

Imagine a piece of paper and a rubber stamp... it's a quick thing to just tap the paper with the stamp to add it... now how do you remove that stamp from the paper? That's how SnapChat filters work.

They are embedded and part of the photo. In order to remove them, you would use standard photo retouching techniques which can be done through photoshop.